# Pound sign a bunch of code at once in psychopy for mac

Tags: python, command

this is a very basic question, but is there a way to put '#' next to a highlighted bunch of code in psychopy for mac?

Edit: if you are using psychopy for mac you can press ctrl-' to input, ctrl-shift-' to remove.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python and everything to do with your editor, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: This is completely up to you editor. If you could specify this we could potentially tell you the bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments said, this is an editor issue and not a Python programming question.  The closest thing there is to a "standard Python editor" is probably the one built into Idle, the IDE that comes with every CPython distribution.  There, you can

1. Highlight the lines you want to comment out
2. Use `Format>Comment Out Region` from the menu or press `Alt+4` at a PC keyboard.

This works in the module editor, not the shell, and uses a double pound sign as a hint that the lines were commented-out in a block operation.

Any editor with regular expression search and replacement and also with a "replace all within selection" option will work, too.  Just highlight the lines and change all occurrences of `^` to `#` within that selection.